# Replace patterns in a string

Tags: ksh

how can I replace every comma within a string with the following string
Single quote comma single quote

Example:

```
US1,US2,US3 ->  US1','US2,','US3
```

I  tried using the following command

```
a=US1,US2
echo ${a/,/\',\'}
```

But it is replacing only the first comma, and not all.

I know how to use sed for this but I am looking for more brief solutions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all instances of a string using parameter expansion, use this syntax to change every 'needle' in `$haystack` into a 'pin':

```
echo "${haystack//needle/pin}"
```

For instance:

```
$ foo="yabbadabbadoo"
$ echo "${foo//a/_}"
y_bb_d_bb_doo
```

You have to escape special characters though:

```
$ foo="milk,eggs,pancake mix,butter"
$ echo "${foo//,/','}"
milk,eggs,pancake mix,butter
$ echo "${foo//,/\',\'}"
milk','eggs','pancake mix','butter
```